# MySql If without the second result

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use MySql's single line IF like this:

`SELECT IF(1>2,2)` instead of specifying the third result `SELECT IF(1>2,2,3)`.

I need to use this in an update where I intend doing:

update table set `IF(type = 10,2) //If type = 10 then 2 or do nothing.`

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `IF(type = 10,2,null)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN type = 10 THEN 2 
         ELSE NULL
       END AS type 
FROM   my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in an update, you can put the condition in the update sentence:

```
UPDATE table
SET x = 2
WHERE type=10
```